# how to get modal to overlap div in html and css?

Tags: html, css

i have a modal but its getting overlapped with another div how to fix that?
screenshot image is attached below
i want to show the modal when clicking on a button

but there is a floating menu bar and its overlapping the moadal showing as shown in screenshot

my code for modal is

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <table class="table table-dark text-center" style="width: 100%;height: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="width: 50%">
                            <iframe
                                class="embed-responsive-item card-img-top"
                                src=""
                                id="mLink"></iframe>
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <span id="mStandard"></span>th 
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <span id="mMedium"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <span id="mSubject"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <span id="mChapter"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="width: 50%">
                            Teacher's Actions:<br>  <span id="mTeacher"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="width: 50%">
                            Student's Actions:<br><span id="mStudent"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank"
                                id="mVideo">Watch Video</a>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just increase modal's z-index. You can try something like z-index:9999999 to make sure that solves it.

By the way, you shouldn't be coding your layout with tables. It seems easier, but code becomes dirty and difficult to maintain with the time.